# Why does my list/array change in dimension when I append a lot of images?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

It is weird, because I want to load PNG images with OpenCV from a directory in Google Colab using Python, and save them in a list and then pass them to a numpy array in order to work with ML algorithms(all images are normalized for the same square size an PNG format). This method worked for me in other similar tasks, but in this case, the output shape of the numpy array changes. The expected output to `array.shape()` should be a numpy array of *(number of images, Height, Width, 3 color channels)* and I get a numpy array of *(number of images, )*

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

X_Covid = []
X_Normal = []


files_covid = glob.glob(COVID_dir + '/*' )
files_normal = glob.glob(NORMAL_dir + '/*')


for myFile_covid in files_covid:
    image_covid = cv2.imread(myFile_covid)
    if image_covid is not None:
      X_Covid.append(image_covid)


for myFile_normal in files_normal:
    image_normal = cv2.imread(myFile_normal)
    if image_normal is not None:
      X_Normal.append(image_normal)

X_Covid=np.asarray(X_Covid)
X_Normal=np.asarray(X_Normal)

print('X_Covid shape:', X_Covid.shape)
print('X_Normal shape:', X_Normal.shape)
```

The expected output should be:

```
X_Covid shape: (1000,240,240,3)
X_Normal shape: (1000,240,240,3)
```

I got:

```
X_Covid shape: (1000,)
X_Normal shape: (1000,)
```

The part I find weird is that if I only pass the first 10 images to the list I get the desired shape. So I don´t know what to do to get de numpy array I need.

Also I found a similar issue in github [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8766), but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Might be because you have images of different shapes in your list

Comment: Look at one or more of the elements of those arrays

Comment: Try `np.stack(X_Covid)`.

Comment: You were absolutely right @hpaulj and @M Z, I trusted the description of the data set, but there are some of different size. Thanks a lot.